# Good articles for SQL Server Health Check specifically for Web Applications

Tags: sql-server, web-server

I am searching for Database Health check articles specifically for a web application back-end server and SQL Server 2005/2008.

My current checklist includes:

- Index Fragmentation 

- SQL Server logs 

- Mirroring Monitor 

- Backup completion 

- File growth

What else should I look for? Are there good articles specifically for a webapp DBA scenario?

(Note: I don't need to worry about many database users - there is only one user the application itself)

Comment: http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/

Comment: Also see Glenn Berry's diagnostic scripts here: http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two I've found most useful:

- [Brent Ozar's Blitz! Script](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/)
- [Glenn Berry's DMV Diagnostic queries](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/)

*Posting these as an answer since you haven't received any other responses. Also, not sure how long this question will live; it may be viewed by some as a shopping list request that will eventually be obsolete.*

Comment: Since this is for SQLServer 2005/2008, which aren't likely to have many more changes now that 2008R2 and 2012 are the "main branches", I think that the existing legacy codes are sufficient, and there really aren't a lot of shopping list options available here. Better to document the few good resources that everyone turns to so we can close as dupe, as need be. The mods discussed this in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2476/ and we feel this is fine. (No meta post, only one question does not a meta make)

Comment: @jcolebrand Right but Brent's and Glenn's scripts may disappear, they may move to a different web site, etc.

Comment: So very true, but if you're supporting Sql 2005 and don't have some way to get access to Brent Ozars script (which _will_ live on, I'm sure) then ... maybe it's time to upgrade to Sql Server 2018?